# Rotation problems with Vector2 class

Tags: java, libgdx

I used `Vector2` class and did some rotation processes with it. But the results weren't what I expected. And I don't know what the problems are. Look at my code and outputs.

```
Vector2 vec;

vec = new Vector2(5, 0);
vec.setAngle(90.0f);
// I expected output to be "x = 0"
// But it prints "x = -2.1855695E-7" This is problematic.
System.out.println("x = " + vec.x);
// I expected output to be "y = 5"
// And it prints "y = 5" OK. No problem.
System.out.println("y = " + vec.y);

vec = new Vector2(5, 0);
vec.setAngle(180.0f);
// I expected output to be "x = -5"
// And it prints "x = -5" OK. No problem.
System.out.println("x = " + vec.x);
// I expected output to be "y = 0"
// But it prints "y = -4.371139E-7" This is problematic.
System.out.println("y = " + vec.y);

vec = new Vector2(5, 0);
vec.setAngle(270.0f);
// I expected output to be "x = 0"
// But it prints "x = 5.9624405E-8" This is problematic.
System.out.println("x = " + vec.x);
// I expected output to be "y = -5"
// And it prints "y = -5" OK. No problem.
System.out.println("y = " + vec.y);

vec = new Vector2(5, 0);
vec.setAngle(360.0f);
// I expected output to be "x = 5"
// And it prints "x = 5" OK. No problem.
System.out.println("x = " + vec.x);
// I expected output to be "y = 0"
// But it prints "y = 8.742278E-7" This is problematic.
System.out.println("y = " + vec.y);
```

Why some outputs aren't what I expected? Is it bad idea to use `Vector2` class for rotation processes ?

Answer (score 0):

The results you are getting are close to the correct value 0.
Doing exact rotation for arbitrary angles is hard as you are dealing with floating point numbers, which have limited accuracy, but at the same time have to use trigonometric functions (sin, cos) which make us of pi, an irrational number which cannot be stored on a computer correctly:

```
System.out.println(Math.sin(Math.PI));
// prints 1.2246467991473532E-16 but should be 0
```

For rotation in multiples of 90° however you can use `rotate90` which will produce exact results.

For arbitrary angles you will have to live with an approximation which you can work around by allowing a small delta in comparisons.

To have an approximation closer to the exact result, you can try writing your rotation function using doubles instead of floats to get some more precision.

Comment: Even `(float)1` isn't exactly 1. Working with irrationals is irrelevant.